# ssl multi domain website

Tags: security, encryption, https, multilingual

We need to secure a multi-langual web application with SSL (registration, login,..). However, this application is accessed by different domain names, exactly a domain name for each language (domainName.co.uk, domainName.fr, domainName.it and so on). We're looking for the simplest and cheapest solution. We don't want to purchase a certificate for each domain name. Some one has an idea ?
the web server : IIS 6
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can purchase multi-domain certificates from several certificate authorities including GoDaddy who calls them multi-domain certificates or UCC certificates.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase a "wild-card domain certificate" so it will cover `*.whatever.com`  these certificates are a couple hundred dollars.   The benefit is that there is no limit on the sub-domains that it covers.

If you have a mess of TLD's i recommend forwarding over to a "secure"  server for sessions.  Remember the *entire* session must be protected via ssl or there is no point.   Your cookie value will be leaked and an attacker can authenticate without a username/password.  This is gone into grater detail in the Owasp Top 10 for 2010 A3: "Broken authentication and session management".

Another option is that some Certificate Authorities offer quantity discounts,  but you'll still get raped in terms of cost.

Comment: it seems he has completly seperate domains, not sub domains

Comment: Then he will have to purchase completely separate certificates.  Some companies offer quantity discount.

Comment: No, you can get multiple unrelated domains in a single certificate. See for example http://help.godaddy.com/article/3908. GoDaddy charges $90 per year for up to five domains, about twice as much for up to 10 domains, etc. Other CAs do similar.

Comment: @GregS  that is cool i didn't know that.  I'm sure you still have to pay extra for each domain.

Comment: Absolutely, but maybe less than a wildcard cert. I don't know where the crossover is.

Answer (score 0):

UCC seems to be different from MDC, I'm still researching what that is, but on Comodo's site http://www.comodopartners.com/products.html they seem to imply that UCC is more suited for microsoft exchange and office communications server.

I don't think goDaddy offers Multi Domain Certs. Could someone shed some light on the difference between UCC and MDC?